# How to use web3 in a mobile context (ionic)?

Tags: web3js, wallets, mobile-wallet

Hello I am building an ionic app that send transaction to ethereum smart contract.
in web I used metmask but what is the alternative for mobile?
is possible to run an ethereum client in a mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Basically it’s the same as building a web dapp. The only difference is that you need to explicitly specify the Web3 Provider to point out to a running remote node. And you need to sign transactions explicitly (no metamask to so this for you).
Let me know shall you need further details.

Comment: Ok but where to store wallet keys ?

Comment: You can store them encrypted in the app’s cache, and authenticate user before every transaction to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a generic ethereum client implemented with Ionic, I released a simple POC on Github: https://github.com/mottolini/ionic-ethereum

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is "Cipher Browser" Ethereum Wallet app is available for Android and iOS by HardFork Inc.

Comment: I dont need a browser to run an ionic app.

Comment: Its not for to run a app, "Cipher" app is is alternative Ethereum Wallet to "MetaMask" wallet on mobile devices. Might this will help you out.

Comment: cipher is a browser. so it just helps just to launch the web app. what I am building  is a mobile app that needs to interact with ethereum